# How do I upgrade VIM to 7.2 when 7.1 is the only version listed in my aptitude?

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I have two Ubuntu servers on which I'm trying to upgrade VIM to 7.2, but `apt-get install vim` only lists version 7.1 which is already installed. Same with a search in aptitude.

I've made sure my sources are updated, but it looks like they're pulling from either 'intrepid' or 'hardy', which I assume is part of the problem.

How should I go about installing 7.2?

Answer (score 1):

If they are not in your repos and you're using the most up-to-date repos, you can always build it from source. The problem with this is that you will not receive updates to that version from your package manager if it is build from source.

Comment: Well, I'm assuming that 7.2 does exist _somewhere_ in the Ubuntu repositories, right? I think I'm just pulling from an old one.

Comment: Perhaps so, but it may be built against libraries more recent than you've got installed. To be safe, you should either (1) build from source against what you've already got installed (you could use https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall to integrate that better with apt); or (2) install the new vim binary you find, plus the new binaries of all its dependencies, plus the new binaries of all their dependencies AND everything that depends on them, plus...